# How to set a profile for Windows Terminal with user defined environemt variables

Tags: windows, environment-variables, windows-terminal

I would like to create a dedicated profile for Windows Terminal with the following:

1. Update the `PATH` variable.
2. Set some new environment variables.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For any shell in windows terminal:**

Settings > Profiles > [profile] > Command line, and configure this command to set up your environment. You could load a batch script for example, before dropping you back into the terminal

**For PowerShell(s):**

Powershell automatically runs your profile script on start if one exists, stored in `$profile`. Setting variables in that script is probably the cleanest way to handle this.

If you want multiple profiles, then you can change the command line in WT to run a specific script file on starting powershell, similar to what you would do for any other shells:

```
powershell.exe -NoExit -File 'C:\folder\profile-one.ps1'
```

---

Here's a full example of loading a batch file from `c:\test\test-env.bat`:

```
@echo off
set myString=Hello World
```

Then in a new windows terminal profile, use `cmd.exe /k "C:\test\test-env.bat"`

[image: screenshot]

Then the result once you open that profile in WT is that the batch file runs first:

```
C:\test>echo %myString%
Hello World
```

Comment: Could you show example how to run a batch script before using the command line?

Comment: @GeorgeIrwin Sure, I've added steps. The basic idea is to use cmd's `/k` to run a command (execute the batch file) and stay open

Comment: Perfect. Though I though there is an internal way to define those.

Comment: What would be the equivalent in PowerShell? Namely running a script and stay open.

Comment: @GeorgeIrwin The equivalent is `powershell.exe -NoExit -F c:\test\test-env.ps1` I had forgotten to add `-NoExit` to my answer, so I've edited that back in